# Change value of variable?

Tags: java, android, xml, time, android-resources

I have a variable from the Application class. I want to change the value of the variable (which originates from the Application class) from another activity. Right now, I can only create an instance of the variable, and then change the value of the instance, which defeats the whole purpose of creating the variable from Application class (so it can be used throughout all activities in project)

Here is the variable. It is a long, and represents the number of activities that have passed by:

[image]

I am trying to change the value of numberOfActivities from every activity by trying to do something like this:

((activityCount) getApplicationContext()).numberOfActivities++;

As you can see here, I am only changing an instance of it. When I try to access the variable later, the value is 0. This shouldn't be the case, as I have declared it static. The popup comes up when I hover over the line saying static member accessed via instance reference. How can I fully change the value of the variable from a separate activity?

Thank you so much, and if you need any more information, feel free to let me know. Any feedback is appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: why screenshots instead of just pasting the code? (I am very puzzled, and I would put several "?" if that was something I do)

Comment: Rich - if someone doesn't get to your issue in a couple days, this site has a "bounty" feature.  you can sacrifice some of your reputation to create a bounty on the question, giving it a lot more activity `:)`

Comment: @siracapsalot I know, but bounties can only be offered in a few days. Also, this is a very beginner question which probably doesn't need bounty to get an answer. Thanks for your time, and feel free to answer if you know about how to change the value of a variable from another activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I just had to set it to System.currentTimeMillis() in the myApplication class itself. Like this:

[image]

Although this is a great workaround, I would love to see a way to access and change it in another class itself.

Answer (score 1):

by doing this:

`currentTime = ((myCurrentTime) getApplicationContext()).currentTime;`

you erase the value of the local `currentTime` by the static one that is initialised at 0.

try doing it the other way around:

`((myCurrentTime) getApplicationContext()).currentTime = currentTime;`

Comment: Oh! So right now I am doing 0 = 0. Could another way to do it be saying: this.currentTime?

Comment: If I do it the other way around, I get the error on the left side: variable expected

Comment: Hi Rich, you changed the question quite a bit, did you manage to fix it?
I am not an android dev, but java.
For android GlobalVariable, you might find the solution in this article: 
http://androidexample.com/Global_Variable_Or_Application_Context_Variable_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=114&aaid=136